# How can I mute a Google+ circle?

Tags: google-plus, mute

I've seen that the main stream is composed of all the singular streams from the various circles. I can mute a single post or contact, but not a circle (all the posts coming from people belonging to that circle) nor compose the main stream in order to specify what circles to draw posts from.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the suggestion on blocking them, but I really don't want these people to be blocked. Let me clarify. I have all my friends and family and colleagues in circles, and they all show in the main stream page (that is, the Google+ "homepage").

I've noticed that many illustrators, comic creators, and public persons I generally follow (on Twitter, and their blogs) have a Google+ page. Due to the nature of Google+, they're using those pages like blogs, to post pictures, and to read news and comics.

In my "virtual world", though, they're second level citizens. I'd just like to follow them once in a while, in my spare time, like "let's see if there is some good new comics", but on a day-by-day use, I don't want my family and friends' posts to be sunk in thousands of less-important-to-me posts!

Comment: So, what you're after is "show me a stream of all of these circles *except* this one", correct?

Comment: Why did you add these people to a circle if you are not interested in what they share with you?  You can have them as contacts without them being in one of your circles if you just want to occasionally send them something.

Comment: @mark4o - I could see times when I don't want to see posts from certain categories.   If I'm offline for a while, I may want to skip over posts from, say, my general "following" circle, while catching up on posts from friends and coworkers.

Comment: You'll not be able to do this with the apps as it currently exists. Unfortunately, there's not a way to "nest" Circles either. The only viable solution would be to create a special Circle ("people I really want to hear from") and put all of the people you want into that one in addition to the Circle(s) they're already in.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has been fixed recently.  Go to your Circles, right click on the circle you want to throttle or mute, and select "Show stream from this circle".  At the top of the stream you will notice a slider that lets you adjust how much you want to see from that stream, including all and nothing.

Comment: This also applies to the bizarre publicly-viewable stuff from people you don't know, which you never asked for, but which Google+ shows you anyway.  There's a "What's Hot" section under your circles, and you can slide it all the way to the left to shut them up for good.  Hopefully.

Answer (score 11):

There is a Google Chrome extension called [Plus Minus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pidkbnhjgdngcfcaikoocdanfijkgdli) which allows you to selected the circles that you see in your stream.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Given that Google+ is still in beta, why don't you make a suggestion [here](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/learnmore/forum/) that you'd like to control how often you get updates from your circles.

You get to this from the Options Icon > Send Feedback.

Comment: @pistacchio: URL of your post?

Answer (score 5):

What I did was make a circle called "Stream" - then I added everyone to this circle that I wanted to see posts from. To make it even easier, I then made my bookmark point to Google+ with my "Stream" circle filter on.

I suppose this is not the ideal way but it's pretty easy - hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Create [a blocked circle](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1358051&answer=1047934) to ignore streams from certain people.

- You won't see their content in your stream.
- They won't be able to comment on your content.
- They will be removed from your circles.
- They will still be able to see your public posts.

Say one of these people you want to mute is Pepper.

1. Go to the user's profile
2. Click **Block Pepper** at the bottom of the sidebar

   - A popup will display and confirm what is about to happen.
3. Click **Block Pepper**

To block someone [while in the circle editor](http://www.google.com/support/profiles/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=1257347&answer=1254208):

1. Select the person you'd like to block.
2. Select **More actions** in the top corner.
3. Select **Block** in the drop down menu.

They are now in a blocked circle. You'll see this as a red circle labelled "Blocked" with a line-through on the Circles page.

Continue adding other people to this circle so that you don't have to read any of their streams.

Comment: Blocking is quite a bit stronger than muting.  Instead just remove everyone from that circle.  If you block those people that will do the same thing, plus other things that the OP did not ask for.

Comment: It's probably an extreme, but for now it's the only equivalent @mar